# Undefined Variable right after assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I' trying to iterate through an array assigned to a variable, but the IDE I am using tells me that the variable is undefined. I tried to trouble shoot the problem by using `console.log(variable_name.length)` and it successfully returns the length of the array, but it still tells me that the variable is undefined when trying to iterate through it.

```
function availableActions(state, reward_matrix) {
  var current_state_row = reward_matrix[state];
  console.log(current_state_row.length);

  let av_act = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < current_state_row.length; i++) {
    if (current_state_row[i] != 0) {
      av_act.push(i);
    }
  }

  return av_act;
}
```

After trying to run the script I get the following error:

```
TypeError: current_state_row is Undefined
```

This example program returns `undefined` among a series of arrays. I believe that is what is causing the error.

MRE

```
function getRand(min, max) {
  let rand = Math.random();
  let number = rand * (max - min) + min;
  number = Math.round(number);
  return number;
}

let total = 0;

let grid = new Array(100)
for(var i = 0; i <100; i++){
  grid[i] = []
  for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
    grid[i].push(0)
    total++
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  let x = getRand(0, grid.length);
  console.log(grid[x]);
}
```

Comment: Wahat guarantees that the value of `reward_matrix[state]` is not `undefined`? It can very well be if `state` is not one of the keys of `reward_matrix`.

Comment: Before assigning anything, check that there's data avaibale in those parameters. try `if(Object.keys(reward_matrix).length > 0 && state)` and put assignment inside the `if()` statement

Comment: Can you share me what state and reward_matrix contains at least some dummy data

Comment: @Karrthik State is a number that falls within the range of the length of the reward matrix. The reward matrix is a multidimensional array containing several arrays of numbers.

Comment: @CarterDugan is this being called in a for loop? and are you sure the state is key that is present in reward_matrix and state is also not undefined?

Comment: @Karrthik Here is some more information. When using console.log(current_state_row) I get [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] which is what I want. When I tell it to iterate through this array to check for which values are zeroes (the code above), it tells me it is undefined.

Comment: @CarterDugan, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As you can see from all the questions, you haven't provided us with one.

Comment: I called the function with made up input and it works fine. @CarterDugan There us something missing in what you've shared with us. Again, provide code that we can run that reproduces your problem.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/LovableForthrightBinarysearchtree. Can you check this link and let me know if it is what you are looking at?

Comment: @Inigo I have now included one.

Answer (score 0):

The MRE provided does produce `undefined` on some iterations of the loop because of  an off-by-one logic flaw. It should use `Math.floor`, not `Math.round`.

So either you are making a similar logic flaw in your original problem, or the provided MRE is  *not* an MRE of that original problem.